# Python - Printing words by length

Tags: python, sorting, output

I have a task where I have to print words in a sentence out by their length.
For example:

```
Sentence: I like programming in python because it is very fun and simple.
>>> I
>>> in it is
>>> fun and
>>> like very
>>> python simple
>>> because
```

And if there is no repetitions:

```
Sentence: Nothing repeated here
>>> here
>>> Nothing
>>> repeated
```

So far I have got this so far:

```
wordsSorted = sorted(sentence, key=len)
```

That sorts the words by their length, but I dont know how to get the correct output from the sorted words. Any help appreciated. I also understand that dictionaries are needed, but Im not sure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First sort the words based on length and then group them using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) again on length:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby         
>>> s = 'I like programming in python because it is very fun and simple'
>>> for _, g in groupby(sorted(s.split(), key=len), key=len):
    print ' '.join(g)
...     
I
in it is
fun and
like very
python simple
because
programming
```

---

You can also do it using a `dict`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for word in s.split():
    d.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
...
```

Now `d` contains:

```
>>> d
{1: ['I'], 2: ['in', 'it', 'is'], 3: ['fun', 'and'], 4: ['like', 'very'], 6: ['python', 'simple'], 7: ['because'], 11: ['programming']}
```

Now we need to iterate over sorted keys and fetch the related value:

```
>>> for _, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print ' '.join(v)
...     
I
in it is
fun and
like very
python simple
because
programming
```

---

If you want to ignore punctuation then you can strip them using `str.strip` with `string.punctuation`:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> s = 'I like programming in python. Because it is very fun and simple.'
>>> sorted((word.strip(punctuation) for word in s.split()), key=len)
['I', 'in', 'it', 'is', 'fun', 'and', 'like', 'very', 'python', 'simple', 'Because', 'programming']
```

Comment: I'll wait to see if anyone can provide an answer that uses a dictionary. If not, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user3036519 My second answer is using a dictionary only.

Comment: You can do for the second method like for v_list in sorted(d.values()):    print ' '.join(v_list)

Comment: To add one though. If there is a comma or full stop in the sentence, it will also be added to the output.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam Wrong! you cannot apply sorted on values here, as lists are compared item wise not by length. And second one can easily be handled using `str.strip` call with `string.punctuation`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a `defaultdict` (or a regular dict) in O(N) time. sort+groupby is O(N log N)

```
words = "I like programming in python because it is very fun and simple".split()
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    D[len(w)].append(w)

for k in sorted(D):
    print " ".join(d[k])
```

```
I
in it is
fun and
like very
python simple
because
programming
```

Comment: So, `sorted(D.items())` is `O(N)` here?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, it's O(M log M) where M is the number of distinct lengths. M is usually going to be much smaller than N, but indeed the worst case is M==N

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
str='I like programming in python because it is very fun and simple'

l=str.split(' ')
sorted(l,key=len)
```

it will return

```
['I', 'in', 'it', 'is', 'fun', 'and', 'like', 'very', 'python', 'simple', 'because', 'programming']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary simplifies it

```
input = "I like programming in python because it is very fun and simple."
output_dict = {}
for word in input.split(" "):
    if not word[-1].isalnum():
        word = word[:-1]
    if len(word) not in output_dict:
        output_dict[len(word)] = []
    output_dict[len(word)].append(word)
for key in sorted(output_dict.keys()):
    print " ".join(output_dict[key])
```

This actually removes the comma, semicolon or full stop in a sentence.